# Send md5 hash or raw password over HTTPS in app

Tags: ios, web-services, security, hash, md5

I my app i do login by email

**First login / Registration**

***Client***

- inputs password
- md5 hash is calculated
- md5 hash is stored in keychain (safe place on clinet)
- md5 hash is send to server (HTTPS)

***Server***

- takes md5 hashed password and uses bcrypt with salt to store it
- issues back a communication token

***Client***

- List item
- uses token until it expires

---

**Automatic relogin**

***Client***

- pulls out the md5 hash out of the keychain
- sends to server (HTTPS) ...

---

**Manual relogin**

***Client***

- user inputs password again
- md5 hash is calculated (and stored)
- md5 is send to server...

The articles i read however, send (and store) the password as raw on client

**Is it any advantage to deal with the md5, over sending it raw (through HTTPS) ? (are there any problems?) (in theory a user could enter another password with the same md5, and still be able to login - is this a valid concern?)**

**Is this mechanism described above legit?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is it any advantage to deal with the md5, over sending it raw (through
> HTTPS)?

In therm of security, I would say that not really, HTTPS already prevents [man in the middle attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack) so if someone tried to sniff the password it wouldn't work either way. You won't get much from hashing your password on client-side in that case.

On the other hand, you might want to consider that when you send the server an MD5 you can't enforce rules to the password or do any sort of operation with the password. So you might want to send the password as it is to the server and let it handle the "password storing logistic".

> in theory a user could enter another password with the same md5, and
> still be able to login - is this a valid concern?

This is totally possible because MD5 (or any hashing algorithm) will take an arbitrary size string and "convert" it to a fixed-size string, having said this in practical terms this is unlikely so you shouldn't worry about this aspect too much. Something that might be more important than this is using a good hashing algorithm and combine it with a "salt", in case of attackers getting a hold of the data it makes it harder for them to crack the password by using precomputed hash tables.

Comment: on the client side, is it an advantage to handle the password as md5 always?

Comment: Since you are already using keychain to store/handle the password, no. Does it hurt to handle the password as MD5 all the time? No. In my opinion it's just a overkill.

Comment: Something I didn't think of before saying "it doesn't hurt to handle the password as MD5" is that you might want to do some extra operations with the password before storing it, and handling the password in your client APP means you can't do that. What I mean with that? Well, imagine you want to check if the password is strong or meets a few rules. You can't ensure that is going to happen in the client side and you can't check it in the server side since it's going to be hashed.

Comment: What “famous ‘collision table’ attack” are you talking about?

Comment: @Gumbo I'm referring to the attack where you have knowledge of an  input that will generate the same provided hash, and the known input is not necessarily be the same input (password in this case) provided by the user (because pure MD5 hashing have collision problems). I hope this makes sense, if not you can read more about it here http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/ and here  http://learncryptography.com/hash-collision-attack/